# Combining ASP:Repeater and JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the next C# code (which works):

```
    // Write data into the checkboxes
    RepeaterVocabularyWords.DataSource = new[] { correctWord1, correctWord2, incorrectWord1, incorrectWord2 };
    RepeaterVocabularyWords.DataBind();  

    // Get data from the checkboxes
    protected void ButtonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepeaterVocabularyWords.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item
                || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                CheckBox CheckBoxVocabularyWord = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("CheckBoxVocabularyWord");
                if (CheckBoxVocabularyWord.Checked)
                { 
                }
            }
        }
```

And the next ASP with JQuery code (which works):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id$='ButtonAccept']").click(function (e) {
        if ($('span.storeCheck input:checked').length != 2) {
            alert("You have to choose only the 2 words that means the same!");
            e.preventDefault();
}
```

Then, if I write the line "span class="storeCheck"..," the above repeater code works, but not the above c# code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterVocabularyWords" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>            
        <<span class="storeCheck"><input runat="server" type="checkbox" ID="CheckBoxVocabularyWord" title="<%# Container.DataItem %>" /></span>  
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On contrast, if I write "asp:CheckBox ID="..," the above c# code works, but not the jQuery stuff.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterVocabularyWords" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxVocabularyWord" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>"   />    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How could I make both work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach of Ray I think would work, but it is what I did finally.

The Jquery code is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[id$='ButtonAccept']").click(function (e) {
            if ($('span.storeCheck input:checked').length != 2) {
                alert("You have to choose only the 2 words that means the same!");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the Repeater is:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterVocabularyWords" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterVocabularyWords_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span class="storeCheck">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxVocabularyWord" Font-Size="0px" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>"
                ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="{labelOn: '<%# Container.DataItem %>', labelOff: '<%# Container.DataItem %>', easing: 'easeOutBounce', duration: 500}" />
        </span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I'm writing a game. I'll put the link here if I finally upload it somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `<input type='checkbox' runat='server'>`, you get an `HtmlInputCheckBox`, not a `CheckBox`. Change your c# code to use the proper class and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For getting data it probably will work, but I still don't know how to write the data into the checkboxes.

Comment: I don't understand - what data do you want to 'write into the checkboxes'?

Comment: My mistake. Reading it again after gaining some more experience I think your idea probably  will work. Anyway I follow the other aproach: I modified the asp code instead the c# one. I'm going to post it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id$='ButtonAccept']").click(function (e) {
        if ($('span.storeCheck').find('input:checked').length != 2) {
            alert("You have to choose only the 2 words that means the same!");
            e.preventDefault();
}
```

by keeping asp checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too :)
But it does not work correctly yet. The condition is always true no matter how many checkboxes are checked.